# Why touches on bottom left part of the screen are delayed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I found this problem when placing button on the very bottom of the screen, and overriding `highlighted` property. `didSet` is called much later (more than 1 sec) on left part of my button than on right part...

After short research I've found this problem is present in all (most?) apps. Let's take App Store app. If you tap and hold tab bar items on the right half of the screen, app will change tab in split second. But if you tap and hold any tab item on left half, you have significant delay before tab changing.

Normal taps (without holding your finger) works as usual, so I guess it's problem with other gesture recognizers, capturing finger tracking and releasing after delay when nothing interested has happened (and normal taps are just forwarded immediately). So far I found this problem only in bottom left corner, which is counter intuitive. I suspected bottom control panel, or swipe back recognizers, but that should affect more than one corner of the screen?

Real question (aside of "why it's happening") is: how can I remove that delay?

Edit: (clarification) By "tap and hold" I mean "place your finger and don't take it back".

Comment: report the 'bug' to __[Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com)__.